# PHPUnit Error Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mock_Game_073a8e20::method()

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I am currently watching a guide using PHP Unit somehow I always get this error when there is mocking involved.

Game Class

```
class Game {

    protected $title;   protected $imagePath;   protected $ratings;

    public function getAverageScore(){

        $ratings = $this->getRatings();         $numRatings = count($ratings);

        $total = 0;

        if($numRatings == 0){           return null;        }


        foreach($ratings as $rating){

            $total = $rating->getScore();

        }

        return $total / $numRatings;

    }

    public function isRecommended()
    {
        return $this->getAverageScore() >= 3;
    }

    public function getTitle(){         return $this->title;    }

    public function setTitle($value){       $this->title = $value;  }

    public function getImagePath(){         if($this->imagePath == null){           return '/images/placeholder.jpg';       }       return $this->imagePath;    }

    public function setImagePath($value){       return $this->imagePath = $value;   }

    public function getRatings(){       return $this->ratings;  }

    public function setRatings($value){         return $this->ratings = $value;     }

}
```

Test Case

```
public function testAverageScore_With6And8_Returns7(){

    $ratings1 = $this->getMock('Rating', ['getScore']);
    $ratings1->method('getScore')
             ->willReturn(6);

    $ratings2 = $this->getMock('Rating', ['getScore']);
    $ratings2->method('getScore')
             ->willReturn(8);

    $game = $this->getMock('Game', ['getRatings']);
    $game->method('getRatings')
         ->willReturn([$ratings1, $ratings2]);
    $this->assertEquals(7, $game->getAverageScore());

}
```

Error:

> E:\xampp\htdocs\gamebook>phpunit src/Test/Unit/GameTest.php PHPUnit
>   3.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann.
>
> ... Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Mock_Rating_5c2598e3::method() in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\gamebook\src\Test\Unit\GameTest.php on line 40
>
> Call Stack:
>       0.0670     126024   1. {main}() E:\xampp\php\phpunit:0
>       0.1800     361592   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() E:\xampp\php\phpunit:46
>       0.1800     365008   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() E:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:129
>       0.3070    1401944   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() E:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:176
>       0.3200    1614568   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() E:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner.php:349
>       0.3810    1873016   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->runTest() E:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php:745
>       0.3810    1873016   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() E:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php:775
>       0.3810    1872984   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() E:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase.php:776
>       0.3820    1873600   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() E:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult.php:648
>       0.3830    1904096  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest() E:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase.php:831
>       0.3830    1904592  11. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() E:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase.php:976
>       0.3830    1904704  12. GameTest->testAverageScore_With6And8_Returns7()
>   E:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase.php:976

Comment: the strange think is that work fine for mocking the Rate class and not for the Game class. Check if the class name is correct (do you use a namespace?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function getMock has been deprecated as of PHPUnit 5.4:

> The PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase::getMock() method has been deprecated.
> Please use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase::createMock() or
> PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase::getMockBuilder() instead.

The Rating class is not included in your code, but if it were, you would mock it like this:

```
$ratings1 = $this->createMock('Rating');
$ratings1->method('getScore')
    ->willReturn(6);
```

Also, in your last mocking statement, you are passing in two parameters, but the function:

```
public function getRatings() {
    return $this->ratings;
}
```

doesn't have two parameters, it needs to be:

```
public function getRatings($rating1, $rating2) {      
    return ($rating1->getScore() + $rating2->getScore()) / 2;
}
```

Then you don't mock that call, you call it with the mocked Rating objects:

```
$game = new Game();
$answer = $game->getRatings($ratings1, $ratings2);
$this->assertSame(7, $answer);
```

I think you meant for getRatings to take an array of Ratings, but I leave that to you to code...

Answer (score 0):

To create a partial mock object as in the original code, one could use:

```
\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase::createPartialMock(string className, array methods)
```

So the new code would look like:

```
$ratings1 = $this->createPartialMock('Rating', ['getScore']);
```

Only methods whose names are in the array are replaced with a configurable test double. The behavior of the other methods is not changed.